# when swipe gesture stop view issue

Tags: ios, swift, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I am creating swift application and i am using UISwipegesture i am swiping up and down direction and its work perfectly but when usewr swipe up or down i will hide show view and it hide and show as expected but when swiping stopped i want that view show automatically

let me Show my code for better understanding

**Code**

```
videDidLoad()
    let swipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: 
    #selector(respondToSwipeGesture(gesture:)))
    swipe.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizer.Direction.up
    swipe.delegate = self
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipe)

    let swipe1 = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(respondToSwipeGesture(gesture:)))
    swipe1.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizer.Direction.down
    swipe1.delegate = self
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipe1)



  @objc func respondToSwipeGesture(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {
        if let swipeGesture = gesture as? UISwipeGestureRecognizer {
            switch swipeGesture.direction {
            case UISwipeGestureRecognizer.Direction.up:
                print("Swiped up")
               viewFilter.isHidden = true
            case UISwipeGestureRecognizer.Direction.down:
                print("Swiped down")
               viewFilter.isHidden = true
            default:
                break
            }
        }
    }
```

here you can able to see that on up down direction i hide view but when swipe stop i want that again show that view so i cant under stand how to do that can any please help me

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigesturerecognizer/1619998-state Every gesture recog. has state property

Comment: if swipeGesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended { print("end") } do as per this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `state` for gesture recognizer:

```
    @objc func respondToSwipeGesture(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    if let swipeGesture = gesture as? UISwipeGestureRecognizer {
        switch swipeGesture.direction {
        case UISwipeGestureRecognizer.Direction.up:
            print("Swiped up")
            viewFilter.isHidden = true
        case UISwipeGestureRecognizer.Direction.down:
            print("Swiped down")
            viewFilter.isHidden = true
        default:
            break
        }
        if swipeGesture.state == .ended {
            viewFilter.isHidden = false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What about the `.failed` case ?

Comment: use `.failed` instead of `.ended`

Answer (score 3):

Use the `UIGestureRecognizer.State` [appledoc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigesturerecognizer/state)

In your selector do something like this

```
@objc func respondToSwipeGesture(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    if let swipeGesture = gesture as? UISwipeGestureRecognizer {
        switch swipeGesture.direction {
        case UISwipeGestureRecognizer.Direction.up:
            print("Swiped up")
           viewFilter.isHidden = true
        case UISwipeGestureRecognizer.Direction.down:
            print("Swiped down")
           viewFilter.isHidden = true
        default:
            break
        }

        // code for looking up which state the gesture currently is in.
        switch swipeGesture.state {
            case .ended, .failed:
                viewFilter.isHidden = false
            // list up other cases here
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the [ended state](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigesturerecognizer/state/ended) of `UIGestureRecognizer` and then show the view. See this [doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigesturerecognizer/state)

```
 @objc func respondToSwipeGesture(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    if let swipeGesture = gesture as? UISwipeGestureRecognizer {
        if swipeGesture.state == .ended {
            viewFilter.isHidden = false
        }
    }
}
```